Is there a way to use a second Mac with its own OS to transfer elements and windows back and forth easily?
I have a newer Mac (MacBook Pro 2019) and an older one (iMac 2011).
For many reasons having to do with the fact that neither computer is compatible with the entirety of my software and devices, I often have to transfer files back and forth. Box or AirDrop work with more or less success but are generally slow and limited.
Where it gets difficult, or impossible, is when I want to transfer open app pages of a document I'm working on (think for example of a RTFD document that I want to keep working on on the other computer because it has pictures I want to add), or browser pages with tabs.
I was thinking that it would be amazing to be able to drag and drop these from one computer to another on the same network, the same way adding a slave screen to a Mac does, with the only difference that each computer would have its own OS.
Is there a way to do that?
Note: I have heard of Handoff, but I am not sure it handles tabbed browsing, and not sure if it will replace existing windows on the target device. I would rather select what I am sharing with each device by dragging it, rather than enable sharing for everything across both devices.



I do this between 3 computers with all the files stored on my iCloud. Save and close the file on one and then open on the other... flawless.

@SolarMike can you drag a webpage with several tabs like in the drawing?
